# HTTP host property in header error (host property )

Tags: c#, http, post

Dears
iam trying to do a POST HTTP
now iam using Postman -on postman it working fine without any error and iam getting data
but when i wite the code iam getting and error

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

i compared the code i found the postman adds some headers like User-Agent,Accept,... i unchecked them all to see which one is affecting i found on postman that the host property if i uncheck it ,it give an error all other are not needed
so but as i know that the host is calculated at runtime  ,i tried to put the host in the code but no luck can anyone help
this is my code

```
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://XXXX.XXXX.XXXX/api/v2/EEEE/login");
        login l = new login();
        l.user = "XXX";
        l.password = "XXXX@123";
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
       // request.Host = "XXXX.XXXX.com";
      //  request.ContentType = "application/json";
        //request.Headers.Add("Host", "XXX.XXX.XXX);
        request.Headers.Add("BSN-XXXX", "XXXXX");
        request.Headers.Add("BSN-XXXX", "XXXXXXXX");
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        //request.Referer = "XXXXXX.XXXX.COM";
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }


         //request.KeepAlive = false;
        //    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | //SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    }
```

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare working postman with non working c#.  Check in the sniffer the TLS version of the headers in the first request.  With the 400 error you probably need to add System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Comment: i added System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 but same error

Comment: I said use a sniffer.  There are too many reasons for the error you are getting to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this code and it works fine

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://XXXX.XXXXXX/api/v2/jumana/login/");
           // client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("XXX", "XXXX");
            request.AddHeader("XXXX", "XXXXX");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\"user\":\"ZZZZZZ\",\n\"password\":\"CUXXXBXZAE@XXX\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```